# excel, sumif...with and or condition

Tags: excel-formula

i tried to adapt this post to mine and did have success:

[Using SUMIFS with multiple AND OR conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238816/excel-using-sumifs-with-multiple-and-or-conditions?newreg=d3c4badf14904e329a059d6a2b836f9a)

it is almost that one, but I'm stuck.

```
A        B      C      D          E      F
n/a     name   S/F  due date    cut by  cutter
        abc    25   Sep-29      Sep-28   H
        cde    30   Sep-29      Sep-27   E
        efg    35   Sep-29      Sep-27   E
        abc    40   Sep-29      Sep-27   H
```

Want do sumif or something  that result in: classify by cutter and date, like this:

```
            9/27        9/28        9/29

Eleanor     65 s/f      00 s/f      00 s/f
Hernan      40 s/f      25 s/f      25 s/f
```

using the following:

```
=SUMIF(G3639:G3653,"="&Y3654,C3639:C3653)+SUMIF(F3638:F3654,"="&Z3653,C3638:C3654)
```

it is working double, if I filled my column F with date, its sum twice, I also tried to use "*" instead "+" and didn't work...

I know its make sense to me, and wont for anyone who is reading, but it is a start.

----------above was an example, below real--------------

........"B"......"C"........."E".........."F"......... G

.....customer.....S/F.......Pick up......Cut by:.....Cutter

.....Chelmsford....76.5.....9/30/2014....9/25/2014....1

.....Chelmsford....24.5.....9/30/2014....9/23/2014....1

.....Chelmsford....14.5.... 9/30/2014....9/22/2014....2

.....Newtonville....48.5....9/30/2014....9/25/2014....1

.....Newtonville......7.....9/30/2014....9/24/2014....2

.....Wakefield.......46.....9/30/2014....9/23/2014....2

.....Harvard........92.5....9/30/2014...9/21/2014.....2

.....N. Reading......27....9/30/2014....9/23/2014.....1

.....N Chelmsford....45....9/30/2014....9/24/2014.....2

.....summary at "Y"     "Z"
                       9/21    9/22  etc
    cutter      1
    cutter      2

```
=SUMIF(G3:G11,"="&Y3,C3:C11+SUMIF(F3:F11,"="&Z3,C3:C11)
```

again, looking for production by cutter (1&2) and also by date cut

Comment: sorry, E & H is a person name (should say at beginning) so my output were, person E cut 65 on 9/27, 0 on 28 and 0 on 29.

Answer (score 2):

Using your first example, enter the cutter in H2; date in I1; and this formula in I2
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$F$2:$F$5,$H2,$E$2:$E$5,I$1)
With some minor range adjustments you can then drag the formula across and down

Comment: Check your sheet. Your data must be in the range as shown in your post above (B1:F5). The results will be H2, H3, etc for the cutter. I1, J1, K1, etc for the date. Formula will go in I2. Double click the formula to check the range.